# Modify fluentd json output

Tags: json, fluentd

How can we easily transform with fluentd( and plugins ) something like this

```
{
    "remote": "87.85.14.126",
    "city": "saint-hubert"
}
```

To this:

```
{
   "geoip": {
       "remote": "87.85.14.126",
       "city": "saint-hubert"
   }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: A Fluentd maintainer here. Right now, this is kind of hard to do. But I am trying to work with upstream to make it possible in record_transformer (docs.fluentd.org/articles/filter_record_transformer). Stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks. However, your link seems to be down at this time

Comment: Oops. that was meant to be docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/filter_record_transformer

Comment: @KiyotoTamura Does fluentd support this now?

Answer (score 7):

Based on the answer by repeatedly(https://github.com/repeatedly).

```
<filter test.**>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  auto_typecast true

  <record>
    geoip ${{"remote" => "${remote}", "city" => "${city}"}}
  </record>
</filter>
```